# How to calculate Amazon S3 prices

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to estimate how much I need to pay to store images for my customers on Amazon S3.
I use their calculator but the total seems to cheap. Feels like I am missing something.

Each image is about 3 MB. Using the calculator I get a monthly sum of $21 if I got 60.000 images (180 GB). This seem very cheap indeed.

My servers are on Amazon EC2, do I still need to add transfer in and out to the calculator?

**Calculator:**
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

**Prices:**
http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Please help!

Comment: You haven't taken into account data transfer. Unless this is just for backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no charge for data transfer *between* AWS services. Likewise for data-in. However you will need to pay data-out charges, for your EC2 instances, as well as S3 (if your customers will be pulling data directly out of S3.

Comment: I will in a sense "host" the images and load them to the website directly from Amazon S3. But have I calculated the price wrong (missing some parameters) or is $21 correct for 180GB of storage per month?

Comment: That seems about right.

Comment: It seems to darn cheap :)

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct -

Here are some additional costs.

Data transfer - if all images are looked at by people at their home or office using a browser, once per week, you will pay for 500GB of bandwidth - which would be about $100.

But you could store low res jpegs for this purpose, etc. Adding low res jpegs (which look 'good' at 1000x1000 px, (are only ~150k each) so adds less than 10% to your storage costs.

Data transfer is free for EC2 to S3 in the same region.

Note that if you have bad bugs in your server software, you can hammer on S3 (by say uploading images 1000's of times to the same location - you will pay for that!).

Comment: And also a 320GB HD is only about $40 or less, so Amazon can still make lots of money - but they need 3 or 4 copies, plus other stuff...